# How to show parent domain field in select box in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I am using grails 2.1.0. I need to show a parent domain's field value through parent chain in select box in a gsp page. But I am getting error. So far I have tried as follows ::

my first domain which contains parents as named adtAuditPack >>>

```
    class AdtAuditorSchdlPack {
    ......
    static belongsTo = [adtAuditPack: AdtAuditPack,fiscalYear:FiscalYear]
    ......
}
```

my first parent of above domain named AdtAuditPack >>>

```
class AdtAuditPack {
    ......
    static belongsTo = [auditFirm:AuditFirm]
    ......
}
```

my second parent of adtAuditorSchdlPack named AuditFirm >>>

```
    class AuditFirm {
    ......
    String auditFirmName
    ......
}
```

Now I want to show auditFirm name as optionValue and AdtAuditorSchdlPack.id as optionKey. For that I have the following select as follows >>>

```
<g:select id="auditPack0" name="auditPack0" from="${AdtAuditorSchdlPack?.adtAuditPack?.auditFirm}" style="width: 200px;"
                          optionKey="id" optionValue="auditFirmName" noSelection="['': 'Select One']"
                          required="" class="form-control"/>
```

It's showing the following tool-tip >>

> Cannot reference non-static symbol 'adtAuditPack' from static context

Can anyone please help me on this please ?!!! Isn't there any way to do this ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct the drop down list on Service/Controller and pass via modal to gsp page and use.

The controller/service method will look like:

```
def c = AdtAuditorSchdlPack .createCriteria()
    def results = c.list() {
        and{ 
           // your criteria logic
        }
        order('id', 'asc')
    }
```

Construct the list based on your logic:

```
List auditFirmList= new ArrayList()
        results.each { AdtAuditorSchdlPack adtAuditPack->
            dataReturns.add([id: adtAuditPack?.auditFirm?.id, name: "${adtAuditPack?.auditFirm?.auditFirmName}"])
        }
```

Now you can pass this list via model and use on dropdown as follows.

```
<g:select class=" form-control" id="auditPack0" name='auditPack0'
noSelection="${['': 'Select one...']}" from="${auditFirmList}" optionKey="id" optionValue="name"></g:select>
```

The optionKey and optionValue may red mark in gsp view page, but will work on run.

Comment: thanks for your approach. But What should I write in my criteria logic according to my code ? and what is dataReturns ? it's showing tool-tip that cannot resolve it ? Can you please provide the criteria logic based on my code please

Answer (score 0):

Write an action on your controller which is called by an ajax in your desired gsp page. the action will be called in the page load function. in your controller write a query like where you join your 3 domain and append it to your gsp field.

Comment: Abdu Hye, thanks for your approach. But I am looking for a better way.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to adjust your from attribute. It has to contain some kind of list.

It should look something like this:

```
<g:select id="auditPack0" name="auditPack0" from="${AdtAuditorSchdlPack.list()}" style="width: 200px;"
optionKey="adtAuditPack?.auditFirm?.id" optionValue="adtAuditPack?.auditFirm?.auditFirmName" 
noSelection="['': 'Select One']" required="" class="form-control"/>
```

Or could could supply the list of AuditFirms directly from your controller.

Comment: if I use this option key and value it is red marked and giving error. And I can not list all the audit firm cause there is some selected firm in auditPack